# Invoke HTTP GET over zeromq

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

After reading benchmark results of zeromq , I was wondering if I can give it a try for accessing a ReSTFul API via HTTP GET calls over zeromq.
I want to test if zeromq can provide a Low-Latency Request-Reply mechanism as compared other alternatives like jersey client API, HTTPurl , Apache hc etc.
I want to have this implemented in java so here is what I am trying,
as per a tutorial

**[XREP -> HTTP client](http://zeromq.org/topics:0mq-over-http)**
*With this you could re-use existing web-applications running on a HTTP server as backend workers for a work queue. This is like a reverse HTTP proxy which load-balances across multiple backend HTTP servers.*

```
ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
ZMQ.Socket requester2 = context.socket(ZMQ.XREP);
requester2.connect("http://domainURL/path");
```

But this is wrong as I am getting

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: http
```

I know I haven't coded this properly but it will be helpful if any guidelines or code snippets in java are provided ?

**EDIT**
I found a resource where a python code is calling remote web service as

```
import json
import zmq

# set up zmq socket
sock = zmq.Context.instance().socket(zmq.REQ)
sock.connect('ipc:///tmp/zurl-req')

# send request
req = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'uri': 'http://example.com/path'
}
sock.send('J' + json.dumps(req))

# print response
print json.loads(sock.recv()[1:])
```

So I am trying to modify my java code as below:

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

public class hwclient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ZMQ.Context context2 = ZMQ.context(1);
        ZMQ.Socket sock = context2.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
        sock.connect("ipc:///tmp/zurl-req");
        String req = "{\n" +
                "  'method': 'GET',\n" +
                "  'uri': 'http://domainURI/path/" +
                "}\n";
        sock.send(req);
        System.out.println("-->" + new String(sock.recv(0)));
        context2.term();
    }
}
```

But now the problem is I do not know what should be the value in place of `"ipc:///tmp/zurl-req"`

Comment: saw the example [here](https://github.com/fanout/zurl#description )

Answer (score 0):

Zeromq does not provide high level http protocol tools.

Use tcp with STREAM socket type.

```
ZMQ.Context ctx = ZMQ.context(1);
ZMQ.Socket sock = ctx.socket(ZMQ.STREAM);
sock.connect("tcp://ip:port");
String req = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
sock.send(req);
```

something like this.

You better read the docs about native patterns: [click](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket)

Comment: Thanks ! But is there any way to specify HTTP Dynamic headers for GET request ? As in .header("name":"value")

Comment: Also @marsgpl can you check if `ctx.socket(ZMQ.STREAM);` is working as I didn't find any dependency for `ZMQ.STREAM` in java.
Can you provide any import statement or library name?
I have following 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zeromq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jeromq</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @SaurabhBhoomkar, in java binding there is no STREAM type lol https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zeromq/ZMQ.java

Comment: @SaurabhBhoomkar, ZMQ_STREAM is int 11 in zmq.h, you can try to pass it like number: ctx.socket(11);

Comment: @SaurabhBhoomkar, about headers: surely you can make a string from your set of headers.

Comment: Guess this can't be done in java , there are upstream and downstream socket types present in java though !